# Removing Session in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I want to put security for all the URL's except the login screen URL in spring security,
but I don't want to use session management.

Please help me out in this issue.
my security context file is below

```xml
<security:http pattern="/" security="none" />   

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" access-denied-page="/"   entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of your `intercept-url` tags is wrong. Quote from the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal):

> You can use multiple  elements to define different access requirements for different sets of URLs, but they will be evaluated in the order listed and the first match will be used. So you must put the most specific matches at the top.

Move the `intercept-url` with the universal match pattern to the bottom of the list.